# dynamic columnDef in ng-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I want to assign ng-grid columns name dynamically after value returned from database, but issue is that it get initialized before data return from ajax, and i am not able to recall gridOption    so it showing balnk, so please help me that how can we construct a column name by ajax return   value.

```
$scope.gridOptions =
        {
            data: 'data.Values',
            columnDefs:
            [
                    { field: "ID", displayName: "Record Id" },
                    { field: "Value", displayName: $scope.ColumnName, cellFilter: cellfilterType },                       
        ],

        };
```

where `$scope.ColumnName` coming from below line...

```
 RecordService.getRecords().then(function (data) {  
  $scope.ColumnName=  data.something;
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post HTML part?

Comment: yes sure, <div class="gridStyle"  ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

Comment: its not your HTML but one row. Edit your post and add Full HTML. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks Max for your help, I have done this with of help columnDef as below:

**Step 1:**

```
$scope.colDef = [];
```

**Step 2:**

```
RecordService.getRecords().then(function (data){      
    $scope.colDef=["ColumnName":data.something]    
}
```

**Step 3:**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {   
    data: 'data.UdiValues',  
    columnDefs:'colDef',            
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions  
};
```

Comment: Great!  [Defining Columns](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Defining-columns) explains that you can use a string for columnDefs and nggrid will bind to that $scope property.

Comment: I think in step-2 you should have 'colDef' instead 'columnDefs', no?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set first "default" value and after change it with promise

```
$scope.gridOptions =
        {
            data: 'data.Values',
            columnDefs:
            [
                    {  
                     field: "ID",
                     displayName: "Record Id"
                    },
                    { field: "Value",
                      displayName: "default",
                      cellFilter: cellfilterType
                    },                       
        ]    
        };
```

And now:

```
RecordService.getRecords().then(function (data) {  
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].displayName =  data.something;
 }
```

The Service `RecordService` returns promise therefore we create promise factory like:

```
.factory('RecordService', ['$resource','$q',  function($resource, $q) {
    var data =   {  something: "from service" } ; 

       var factory = {
            getRecords: function (selectedSubject) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();            
               deferred.resolve(data);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
        return factory;
}]);
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/670/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for reply Max, but same issue again..it setting as column name "default". not the new one :(

Comment: I try to reproduce it in plunker, please post full HTML or where you load gridOptions

Answer (score 0):

Something like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187845/default-headercell-template-in-ng-grid/30189859#30189859)

Return json, play around, use GET mapping to strings etc?

Answer (score 0):

i have done something like this :-

```
self.gridOptions.columnDefs = columnDefs(colDef,displayNames);
```

columnDef is :-

```
var columnDefs = function(data,cd){
        var colDef= [];
        var mi = null;
        var colByOrder = sortedByOrder(data); 
        for(var i=0 ; i < colByOrder.length ; i++){
            colDef.push({
                width: width,
                field: String(colByOrder[i][1].position),
                menuItems: menuItems(this),
                displayName: cd[colByOrder[i][1].position],
                enableSorting: false,
                type: 'string',

            });
        }
        return colDef;          
    };
```